# How do you get form data in Ruby similar to Python's cgi.fieldstorage()?

Tags: ruby, forms, form-data, http-post

To help myself learn Ruby, I'm converting a simple Python website I made into Ruby. I can't figure out how to get the form values in Ruby, though. How do I do that?

Comment: Have you looked at any of the popular Ruby web frameworks? Rails may be overkill if you have a small site, but Sinatra is nice and light weight. Both frameworks make these values available via a `params` hash.

Comment: @Beerlington I'm going to look at frameworks eventually, but I'm still learning Ruby and don't want to learn advanced things like Rails yet.

Answer (score 2):

```
require "cgi"
cgi = CGI.new
params = cgi.params # a hash with field-names and their values
```